# Can "mistake(n) as" "mistake(n) for" "mistake(n) with" be used indifferently?

Tags: usage

I'd always used "mistake(n) **for**" until today I came upon

> you could easily be mistaken as one.

I wanted to see if it was correct or if it was a mistake so I looked into the matter and found:

- my dictionaries only give "mistake **for**".

> The doctor mistook the symptoms for blood poisoning. (*Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English*)
>
> You mustn't mistake lack of formal education for lack of wisdom. (*Collins Cobuild*)
>
> Members of an army patrol mistook him for the gunman. ( *BBC English Dictionary*)

- A quick search on the internet showed  "mistake(n) **as**" is quite common, but not as common as "mistaken **for**". This was confirmed by an [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mistaken%20for,mistaken%20as&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,mistaken%20for;,c0;.t1;,mistaken%20as;,c0).

I even found both [on the same page](http://www.fluentin3months.com/native/):

> Why getting mistaken for a native speaker is much easier than you think.

and

> he has never in his life come across a language learner who is mistaken as a native the entire time

I really cannot perceive any difference at all in the meaning of *mistaken as* and *mistaken for* in these two sentences above.

I had the same feeling on [that page](http://books.google.fr/books?id=YdQ-AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA520&lpg=PA520&dq=%22mistaken%20as%20%22%20%22mistaken%20for%22&source=bl&ots=9rzv4fHoMg&sig=co4R7Syb6ePV9-fbDpV0Wkt3FW8&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=zKYYU7PNBoGR4AS8hoCgAw&ved=0CHAQ6AEwCDgK#v=onepage&q=%22mistaken%20as%20%22%20%22mistaken%20for%22&f=false),  where both are used :

> mistaken as 10 mg if the decimal point is not seen expressed in whole numbers
>
> 100000 has been mistaken for 10,000 or ....

That document is pretty consistent in the use of "mistaken **as**" except in a couple of places, so I thought it could be because of different collaborators having different speech habits.

- My browsing even led me to "mistaken **with**"

> [Custom route mistaken with product id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564261/spree-1-1-2-custom-route-mistaken-with-product-id)
>
> [You must have me mistaken with someone else.](http://www.jabberwacky.com/j2convbydate-219part3)

I somehow feel I could use **for** is these two sentences but not **as** but I'm at a loss to say why.

My questions:
- Since apparently **for**,  **with**, & **as** are used in after the verb "mistake" to mean we wrongly think something or someone is something else or someone else, can they be used indifferently ?  If yes, are there nevertheless slight subtleties to be considered?
- Could difference in usage be a matter of regional habits (AmE vs BrE vs AusE etc.)?

Comment: In COCA, *mistaken for* is roughly 20 times more popular than *mistaken as*.  In the Google Books result you linked to, it's about 12 times more common.  Note that the *mistaken as* results are inflated somewhat by standard usage such as *mistaken as to whether*, *mistaken as to how*, *as mistaken as I was*, *not so much mistaken as*, and so on.

Comment: @snailplane: You confirm what I found. And I had since a look at the OED (CDrom edition), nothing mentioned in the definitions but in the examples I found 210 "mistaken for", 6 "mistaken as", 1 "mistaken with".  To put it in a nutshell to answer my question, from what you & Fumble Fingers say although not standard "as" is not perceived as "wrong" and no nuance in meaning intended. Same with "with" that is even rarer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're overanalysing this one. Obviously native speakers often make "slips" like this, especially in casual conversation or Q&A website comment posts.

In the case of *X mistaken for Y*, I imagine almost every competent native speaker would say ***for*** is "correct", but many if not most wouldn't see anything seriously "wrong" with ***as***. A (probably, much smaller) number might not see much wrong with ***with***.

This is an example of a comparatively minor slip. On a site like ELL, for example, many users are native speakers, and many aren't. As it happens, we have contextual information for the specific comment that sparked this question, making it *highly likely* that the writer is in fact a native speaker. But even if there were no such evidence, the fact of the usage itself would be no real reason to suppose otherwise.

---

This shouldn't be taken as a general principle for *all* "misused" prepositions, etc. Some errors are far less likely from native speakers, and far more likely to be seen as "giveaways" indicating "non-native".

Comment: My question was not about one comment post on EL&U, I only mentioned it because it started me thinking and I noticed it was not a one-person slip because I easily found other examples. I was looking for a more general answer about the use of the phrasal verb and not an answer partly about the content of comments on EL&U (even less on ELL). So would the answer to my question be that the only correct form is *mistake for*, all other occurrences are lapses of no consequence and do not convey any nuances in meaning? I'll gladly rephrase my question and eliminate the introduction if it can help.

Comment: @Laure: If you're simply asking about the acceptable range of prepositions that can occur in the construction *"A was mistaken **xxx** B"*, that's covered by my second paragraph. It's bordering on General Reference, even for ELL. It makes no difference how many "non-standard" examples you find not using ***for***. Personally I'd prefer you *not* to amend the question so it just asks "What's the correct preposition" because that's trivial. What's *interesting* is that you've hit on a case where there's no disagreement about what's "correct", yet minor lapses are not particularly "jarring".