# Should you say "mistake a deer as a horse" or "mistake a deer for a horse"?

Tags: prepositions, idioms

That is to say, somebody saw a deer and thought it was a horse, as in the phrase "horse deer" in Japanese: 馬鹿, ばか to mean a fool or idiot:

The complete usage is:

> It is "horse" vs "deer". The story goes, somebody recognized a deer as
> a horse, so he was a fool. So that's why "horse" "deer" means a fool.
> But there is more to this story. **People usually won't mistake a deer
> for a horse**, so what is the real deal? It was in the past, a royal
> official in some dynasty was gaining power, and he wanted to say
> anything and see if people just say he was right. So one day, he
> pointed at some deer and said it was a horse. Some other state
> officials said, "no, it is a deer". But some "smart" officials said,
> "oh yes, it is a beautiful deer". So, that powerful official knew who
> is "smart enough" to say a deer is a horse, to be in a team with him. It
> goes the same way in the current world. If the CEO or director or
> manager in a corporation said something that is stupid or unfair,
> there are people who'd point out it is unfair, but the number can be
> very small. Most people may keep silent, or say that the manager made
> the perfect decision, and it works the same way as "pointing to a deer
> and say it is a horse".

Is it

1. People usually won't mistake a deer for a horse

or

2. People usually won't mistake a deer as a horse

?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can "mistake(n) as" "mistake(n) for" "mistake(n) with" be used indifferently?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18588/can-mistaken-as-mistaken-for-mistaken-with-be-used-indifferently) Also [Mistake x AS y, or mistake x FOR y?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76407/mistake-x-as-y-or-mistake-x-for-y) and [Is it correct to say "I was mistaking it with something"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/190072/is-it-correct-to-say-i-was-mistaking-it-with-something), among others.

Comment: oh you are the person who answered in the first question. I think the 3rd question answered it in terms of objects, rather than something abstract that maybe "thinking or opinion". It doesn't say whether you can use "as" though

Comment: I didn't realise I'd answered on the earlier question. But looking at it now, I see I said *almost every competent native speaker would say **for** is "correct", but many if not most wouldn't see anything seriously "wrong" with **as***. How is that not clear? Note that I'm definitely not suggesting you *should* use ***as*** (obviously you shouldn't *deliberately* chose non-idiomatic forms). I was just pointing out that it's not a *serious* error. But it's not what native Anglophones usually say, so nor should you!